# XPath isn't behaving as expected

Tags: python, xpath

I have some quite messy HTML tag and want to extract the paragraph information, without the HTML, however I'm finding I can only get the first paragraph. So for example the HTML looks like:

```
   <p>BLAH BLAH<strong><nobr><strong>people</strong></nobr></strong>&#39;s work <strong>&quot;Blah <nobr><strong><span style="font-size:14pt"><strong>blah</strong></span></strong></nobr> and <nobr><strong><span style="font-size:14pt"><strong>Nothing</strong></span></strong></nobr> quote&quot;</strong>lalal</p>

<p>More text<strong><nobr><strong>More text</strong></nobr></strong> blah blah</p>
```

I'm attempting with:

```
converted = html.fromstring(body)
para = converted.xpath('//*[starts-with(name(), "p")]')
```

and to loop over the paras:

```
string_content = ''
for p in para:          
    if p.text is not None:
        string_content += ' ' + p.text
```

However I am only getting one `<p>` element, which is the first one. This code seems to be failing in picking up all the content that I need and typically gives just the first piece of information.

Comment: Did you try: `para = converted.xpath('//p')`?

Comment: @gaback yes I tried that initially.

Comment: Check whether all required `p` nodes really present in HTML you get with HTTP-request. They might be generated by JavaScript, so you won't be able to extract them from source code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the content inside the `p` tag, you can do something like this:

```
from lxml import html

body = '<p>BLAH BLAH<strong><nobr><strong>people</strong></nobr></strong>&#39;s work <strong>&quot;Blah <nobr><strong><span style="font-size:14pt"><strong>blah</strong></span></strong></nobr> and <nobr><strong><span style="font-size:14pt"><strong>Nothing</strong></span></strong></nobr> quote&quot;</strong>lalal</p><p>More text<strong><nobr><strong>More text</strong></nobr></strong> blah blah</p>'

converted = html.fromstring(body)
para = converted.xpath('//p')

content = [p.text_content() for p in para if p.text_content()]
content = ' '.join(content)
print content
```

The result is:

```
BLAH BLAHpeople's work "Blah blah and Nothing quote"lalal More textMore text blah blah
```